# appAPI.tabs.getActive returning empty object in firefox

Tags: crossrider

appAPI.tabs.getActive returning empty object in firefox

```
appAPI.ready(function() 
{ 
    // retrieves the information for the active tab 
    appAPI.tabs.getActive(function(tabInfo) { 
        console.log( 
           'tabId: ' + tabInfo.tabId + 
           ' tabUrl: ' + tabInfo.tabUrl 
        ); 
     }); 
});
```

I tried above function/code appAPI.tabs.getActive in my extension, its working properly in Chrome but its not working in firefox, its giving me empty object {}. If somebody know whats the issue is please reply on this asap, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, this only occurs when using [appAPI.tabs](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.tabs) API in a scope other than the background scope.
Please note that it is only supported in the background scope.

To use [appAPI.tabs.getActive](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.tabs-method-getActive) in other scopes, from the scope send a message to the background scope to obtain the tabInfo object, and then send the data back to the original scope, something like the following example in the popup scope:

**popup.html**:

```
function crossriderMain($) {
  var tabInfo = null;
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.type==='set-tabInfo') {
      tabInfo = msg.tabInfo;
    }
  });
  appAPI.message.toBackground({type:'get-tabInfo'});
}
```

**background.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function() {
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.type==='get-tabInfo') {
      appAPI.tabs.getActive(function(tabInfo) {
        appAPI.message.toPopup({type:'set-tabInfo', tabInfo:tabInfo});
      });
    }
  });
});
```